# How to use Parse Cache Policy

Tags: ios, swift, caching, parse-platform

I have tried to implement cache policy using Parse. Here is where I query for data from Parse, and also where I use cache policy:

```
func findEmployeeForLoggedInUser(completion: (array: [AnyObject], error: String?) -> Void) {
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Employee")
        query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheElseNetwork //CACHE POLICY
        query.whereKey("employerId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in
            var employeeArray = [PFEmployee]()
            if let error = error {
                let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? String
                completion(array: employeeArray, error: errorString)
            } else {
                for employee in results! {
                    let currentEmployee: PFEmployee = employee as! PFEmployee
                    employeeArray.append(currentEmployee)
                }
                completion(array: employeeArray, error: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, every time a user logs in or signs up, I used this line of code: `PFQuery.clearAllCachedResults()` to clear all cached results.

When I try to run the app, it crashes and this is the error message in the debug area:

2015-07-16 14:53:38.644 Employee Keeper[73678:5099293] [Error]: Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=Parse Code=209 "invalid session token" UserInfo=0x7fe150712ef0 {code=209, originalError=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)", temporary=0, error=invalid session token, NSLocalizedDescription=invalid session token}
2015-07-16 14:54:01.172 Employee Keeper[73678:5098808] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Method not allowed when Pinning is enabled.'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's written in last line of your log:

```
"Method not allowed when Pinning is enabled."
```

If you look at the [official Parse documentation for `PFQuery`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/cachePolicy), more specifically for the `cachePolicy` property, then it's written:

```
The cache policy to use for requests.
Not allowed when Pinning is enabled.
```

So unfortunately it's currently impossible to mix up the pinning feature and caching functionality.

---

If you are not using the local datastore feature, then I would recommend that you simply disable this and make use of the caching feature.

In case that you rely on the local datastore feature, then I would recommend that you implement some sort of caching feature of your own using the local datastore.